# What exactly does \@doendpe do?

Tags: macros, environments, conditionals, paragraphs, latex-base

Quoting from the [LaTeX2e sources](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf):

> [`\@endparenv`, `\@doendpe`]
>
> To suppress the paragraph indentation in text immediately following a
>   paragraph-making environment, `\everypar` is changed to remove the
>   space, and `\par` is redefined to restore `\everypar`. Instead of
>   redefining `\par` and `\everpar`, `\@endparenv` was changed to set
>   the `@endpe` switch, letting `\end` redefine `\par` and `\everypar`.
>
> This allows paragraph-making environments to work right when called by
>   other environments. (Changed 27 Oct 86)

These are the relevant code lines (with line breaks added to improve readability):

```
\def\@endparenv{%
  \addpenalty\@endparpenalty
  \addvspace\@topsepadd
  \@endpetrue
}
\def\@doendpe{%
  \@endpetrue% <---?
  \def\par{%
    \@restorepar
    \everypar{}%
    \par
    \@endpefalse% <---?
  }%
  \everypar{%
    {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
    \everypar{}%
    \@endpefalse% <---?
  }%
}
```

While I roughly comprehend `\@doendpe` and its `\everypar` trickery, I'm lost with regard to two details (marked with `<---?` in the above code):

- As the definition of `\begin` includes `\@endpefalse`, why is it necessary to set `\@endpefalse` at the end of `\@doendpe`'s `\par`/`\everypar` redefinitions?
- Why is setting `\@endpetrue` at the start of `\@doendpe` necessary? Isn't `\@doendpe` only called if the `@endpe` switch is set to `true`?

I suspect that a possible answer involves the (to me) cryptical remark about *"paragraph-making environments [working] right when called by other environments"*, but would be grateful for a full explanation.

Bonus question: If I were to define a custom list environment that at its end would set `\@endpefalse` and instead (with the appropriate `\aftergroup`) call a carbon copy of `\@doendpe` (say `\@doendcustomenv`), would the code lines marked wih `<---?` above be beneficial or superfluous in this copy?

Comment: Good question. I was asking me the same when I wrote on `macros2e`.

Comment: @Martin: I didn't assume my question was *that* good. ;-)

Comment: I suspect that this has something to do with `lrbox` that does some trickery with grouping. It does `\@endpefalse` at some point.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For our purposes, `\begin{#1}` is roughly

```
\begingroup \@endpefalse \csname #1\endcsname
```

and `\end{#1}` is roughly

```
\csname end#1\endcsname\expandafter \endgroup \if@endpe \@doendpe \fi
```

Since `\expandafter` expands `\if@endpe` before the group ends, the value of the switch that is used is the one within the environment. If the `\csname #1\endcsname` part of a `\begin{#1}` features `\@endpetrue`, then `\@doendpe` will be expanded. However, it will be expanded *outside the environment*, where the switch has been returned to its former value.

Consider the following document. The environment `parenvA` suppresses the indentation afterwards. In the second case, `\@endparenv` is called within two groups, and causes `\@doendpe` to be called still within the `parenvB` environment. If the definition of `\@doendpe` did not have `\@endpetrue`, then it would simply define `\par` and `\everypar` within the `parenvB` environment. These definitions would disappear at the end of the group, and the next paragraph would be indented. So instead, `\@doendpe` makes sure to carry the truth of the switch with it beyond environment boundaries, until the next `\par` or `\everypar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{parenvA}{}{\par\@endparenv}
\newenvironment{parenvB}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
% case 1
\begin{parenvA}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{parenvA}
\lipsum[2]
% case 2
\begin{parenvB}
  \begin{parenvA}
    \lipsum[3]
  \end{parenvA}
\end{parenvB}
\lipsum[4]
% case 3
\begin{parenvB}
  \begin{parenvA}
    \lipsum[5]
  \end{parenvA}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{parenvB}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

Once this is established, both `\par` and `\everypar` must have `\@endpefalse`, otherwise the last paragraph in the example above would lose its indentation: indeed, the `\@doendpe` triggered just outside the `parenvA` environment contains `\@endpetrue`, but we don't want the indentation to be suppressed after that `\end{parenvB}`, because there has already been a paragraph.

Now why do we need to work with both `\everypar` and `\par`? Because there are actually two cases. If the user leaves no blank line after `\end{parenvA}`, then the first letter, inherently horizontal for TeX, causes `\everypar` to be inserted, and to eat the indentation (with `\lastbox`). However, if the user leaves a blank line, TeX's eyes replace that by a `\par` token, which resets the normal definitions of `\par` and `\everypar`, and do not eat any indentation (try adding some blank lines in the file above and see what happens).

For your bonus question, well, if you remove those lines, the indentation will only be removed if the next `\par` (blank line) or `\everypar` (triggered by horizontal material) is within the same group/environment. Not necessarily what you want.