# Why do I have to put the center environment in a group for \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading to suppress indentation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, indentation, grouping

Consider the following two macros, the only difference being that one has the environment inside a group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thisworks{%
  {\begin{center}
    $\ast$
    \end{center}}
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading}

\newcommand\thisdoesnt{%
\begin{center}
  $\ast$
\end{center}
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading}

\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\thisworks

\lipsum[5]

\thisdoesnt

\lipsum[42]
\end{document}
```

Why does the first suppress the indentation while the second doesn't?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having a quick look at the definition of `\end{center}` we see that it just ends a `trivlist`,

```
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

now as to why Lamport would use a `trivlist` to define the `centering` and indirectly the `center` macros is a subject for another question, it suffices at this point to just say he was very fond of them, although I am sure he had some valid reasons for doing so.

Changing your code slightly and introducing a `trivlist` you can observe the effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\thisworks{%
   $$\ast$$
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading}

\newcommand\thisdoesnt{%
  {\begin{trivlist}\item\end{trivlist}}
  $$\ast$$
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading
}

\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\thisworks

\lipsum[5]

\thisdoesnt

\lipsum[42]
\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the grouping brackets at the `\begin{trivlist}` line, you will see the effect. The code  is all interwoven in the source2e.pdf.

To understand better LaTeX's buggy behaviour here, I will illustrate it with another minimal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    

This is the normal behavior of a:
\begin{trivlist}\item list\end{trivlist}
trivlist that is not enclosed in a group.

If you enclose the list in a group the lines after the list:
{\begin{center} center\end{center}}
are indented. LaTeX is buggy in this respect. 

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

If you group `trivlist` or the `center` commands results in the same buggy behaviour.
In your example the latter allows the  `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading` to take effect as it can apply everypar or indent at the beginning of the paragraph, whereas in the first example above, it can't as the following text is considered the last portion of the previous paragraph.

Comment: Ah yes, the pain-in-the-neck hat is "let's define *everything* as a list".

Comment: @JosephWright it fits nicely with the fact that the only data structure in TeX is (token) lists. The only typesetting structure in LaTeX is (triv) lists.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question of _why_ an (ungrouped) trivlist stops the suppressing of indentation...

Comment: @Seamus ...Sorry thought it was obvious:). I added some more detail.

Answer (score 8):

`\endtrivlist` calls `\@endparenv` which will cause `\@doendpe` to be executed which *"suppress[es] the paragraph indentation in text immediately following a paragraph-making
environment"* (LaTeX2e sources, p. 227). `\@doendpe` will override `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading`. Note that you can suppress indentation of the following paragraph by adding  `%` (a comment sign) in the line after `\thisdoesnt` in the document body of your MWE.

See also [What exactly does \@doendpe do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/what-exactly-does-doendpe-do)