# \addvspace{x}\noindent … \addvspace{x} doesn’t work

Tags: spacing

The combination of `\addvspace{x}\addvspace{x}` will cause the skip `x` but `\addvspace{x}\noindent \addvspace{x}` gives a 2`x` skip.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newenvironment{env}{%
    \par\addvspace{2\baselineskip}%
    \hspace*{2em}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\addvspace{2\baselineskip}%
    \noindent\ignorespacesafterend%
}

\begin{document}
Line of text Line of text Line of text Line of text and
\begin{env}
--- \verb+env+ ---
\end{env}
no indent here. Line of text Line of text Line of text.

Next par (with indent). Line of text Line of text Line of text.
\begin{env}
--- \verb+env+ ---
\end{env}

Next par (with indent). Line of text Line of text Line of text.

\begin{env}
--- Two \verb+env+s following ---
\end{env}
\begin{env}
--- dont work with \verb+\addvspace+ ---
\end{env}
\end{document}
```

This example gives the doubled space. If i comment out the line `\noindent\ignorespacesafterend%` in the definition of `{env}` there is a single space with is the desired result but then the line `no indent here ...` will be indented which is not correct, I think.

Is it possible to make `{env}` behave like e.g. `{equation}`?

Comment: You should look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/what-exactly-does-doendpe-do

Comment: With `\noindent` you're starting a paragraph; so the two `\addvspace` are not near to each other any more.

Comment: This is one for `xgalley`!

Comment: @JosephWright: I’m not shure if I understand your comment could you please explain it a little or add it as an answer? (I had a look hat `xgalley.pdf` but didn’t found something useful …)

Comment: @Tobi It was a slightly flippant remark. The idea in `xgalley` is to address these issues in a very different way at a low level. So for example `\noindent` is not 'start a paragraph with no indent' but 'set a flag such that the next paragraph which starts will have no indent'. This allows additive treatment of vspace, but is currently experimental. In any case, unlike other LaTeX3 code you can't just load `xgalley` and expect everything to continue working as before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\noindent`starts a paragraph and if that is immediately followed by an empty line it will be and empty paragraph but still prevent `\addvspace` to look backwards and see the previous `\addvspace`. So this is not the right approach to get the paragraph indentation suppressed.

What you should do instead is a variation of `\@endparenv` namely to set a boolean switch that signals special processing inside `\end{...}`. I.e.,

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{env}{%
    \par\addvspace{2\baselineskip}%
    \hspace*{2em}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\addvspace{2\baselineskip}%
    \@endpetrue                       % <-- this is needed
}
\makeatother
```

As mentioned in a comment the processing that happens to make this "end-magic" work is nicely explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/what-exactly-does-doendpe-do).

Comment: You may be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39867/intextsep-gives-doubled-space