# \addvspace after \section in memoir always adds all its space

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir

Knowing about `\addvspace` I wrote my own environment that adds a minimum space before and after it. But using `memoir`, if a `\section` precedes it, `\addvspace` always adds all its space to the space that usually follows a section. MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec 1}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Sec 2}

\addvspace{\onelineskip}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Sec 3}

\section{Sec 4}

\end{document}
```

You can see that the second section has way too much vspace after it. I had a look at the memoir \@startsection code and found that it does (rightly) use `\vskip` and `\addvspace`. After reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40331/addvspacex-noindent-addvspacex-doesnt-work) question I suspect it is maybe a `\noindent` problem since `\@afterindent` is used. But there must be a trick somewhere that I am missing because Sec 3 and Sec 4 have the proper space. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is that the last skip called by `\section` is `\vskip-\parskip` which is `0pt plus -1pt` and so when `\addvspace` tests whether the last skip is zero (in which case it always adds its space), the test will be true because the first component of the skip is `0pt` (the `plus` part is discarded). To solve your problem, you can put an `\unskip` just before your `\addvspace`.

Comment: Hm.. it sounds promising, but it doesn't quite work yet: it breaks with "You can't use `\unskip` in vertical mode." Is there an equivalent for vertical mode? And a conditional one that only unskips if the `\vskip` was `0pt`?

Comment: @MiB: Sorry, I should have mentioned it, but for `\unskip` to work, you mustn't leave a blank line before it (so it's more a one time quick fix than a real solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha! Thanks to the tip from Philippe I found the following solution:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@xsect}
         {\vskip\@tempskipa\vskip-\parskip}{\addvspace{\@tempskipa}\addvspace{-\parskip}}
         {}{\typeout{WARNING! Patching \noexpand\@xsect failed!}}
\makeatother
```

`\@xsect` didn't use `\addvspace` but plain `\vskip`. Changing that fixes my problem.