# xgalley doesn't like \addvspace

Tags: spacing, errors, l3galley

The following minimal example produce the typical "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing `\item`" error. I can't understand what's wrong with loading [`xgalley`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xgalley) together with the use of `\addvspace`...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xgalley}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{test}
  {\par}
  {\par
   \addvspace{\baselineskip}% <--- error...
   %\@endpetrue
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  abc
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Adding `\@endpetrue` didn't help, as suggested in [`\addvspace{x}\noindent` ... `\addvspace{x}` doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40331/5764).

<sub>The above example can be made smaller by just making a call to `\addvspace` rather than placing it in an environment.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `xgalley` is considered  experimental, and can't be loaded in documents in general, is that it only works with constructs that are specifically designed or modified to work with it. The entire mechanism for vertical mode material is different from the LaTeX2e one. Currently, `\addvspace` isn't modified to work with `xgalley` so an error is unsurprising. A fix at least covering the normal us case is

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \addvspace { m }
  { \galley_vspace_set_single:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This will be added to the release version later today.